# pip can't install package because it can't find swig2.0 binary

Tags: python-2.7, pip, swig

I'm using python 2.7.9 (64 bit) with pip 1.5.6 and virtualenv 12.1.1 on Windows 7 powershell. I created a virtual environment named *NeuralNetwork* and I'm trying to install the package fann2 1.0.7:

```
PS C:\Python27\envs\NeuralNetwork\Scripts> pip.exe install fann2
Collecting fann2
(...)
Exception: Couldn't find swig2.0 binary!
```

I guess I have to install this `swig2.0 binary` for Windows 7, but I can't figure out how exacly. I went to [a swig site I found on Google](http://www.swig.org/download.html) and downloaded swigwin 2.0.12. The zip file came with a pre-compiled `swig.exe`. I read the documentation for Windows, but I didn't understand where should I put this file nor how to proceed afterward. I'm new to python and I've never heard of swig before. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered what the problem was: `swig.exe` wasn't in Windows PATH variable. To fix this:

1. Unzip `swigwin` wherever you want.
2. Add the directory path where `swig.exe`is located to the Windows
   PATH variable.

To add `swig.exe` directory to the PATH variable:

1. Start the System Control Panel applet (Start - Settings - Control
   Panel - System).
2. Select the Advanced tab.
3. Click the Environment Variables button.
4. Under System Variables, select Path, then click Edit.
5. Put a `;` and append the directory path where `swig.exe`is located
   to the end of the strig.

Answer (score 0):

If your Python Scripts folder is on your PATH in Windows (e.g. `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts` for Python 3.9), then you can just `pip install swig`.